# How to keep source URL displayed in redirected address?

Tags: url, redirect

I have registered 2 websites (say *source.com* and *target.info*) but only one (*target.info*) is hosted. I could redirect *source.com* to hosted *target.info/source* but I would like to display *source.com* in the address bar rather than the physical URL *target.info/source* or subdomain *source.target.info*. Is this possible, knowing that I don’t have a .htaccess for *source.com* since it is not hosted?

I tried to redirect *source.com* to *target.info/source* on my registrar account but then I get *target.info/source* in the address bar. Ideally I would like to have *source.com* concatenated with the file names, but *source.com* alone would be fine.

Comment: No, you can't redirect without changing the displayed domain. That would bring along a whole host (pun intended) of potential security issues. An iframe might suit your needs instead.

Comment: I’m pretty sure I once got this to work, but did not keep it because the address bar did not update when changing directory. Now it would be OK ! But I guess the security standards have evolved.

Answer (score 0):

An [alias domain](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/aliases/) might be close to what you are looking for but you may find it called something different if you use a different hosting provider. You will however, still need to point the domain to your hosting provider (in the case of hosting providers using cPanel whose documentation I have linked this would involve changing the nameservers at your registrar).

Form the docs:

> Domain aliases are domains that you own, but which do not contain any content. Instead, they point to the contents of another domain or subdomain on your account. This is useful, for example, to hold a domain that you will later sell, or to redirect traffic to another domain.

Comment: Thanks, this link seems relevant but I am not hosted nor registered there.
https://docs.gandi.net/en/web_hosting/common_operations/link_to_domain.html

Comment: @AlexandreOberlin, cPanel is a brand of management software not a hosting provider or domain registrar. For Gandi you could perhaps try adding an [ALIAS DNS Record](https://docs.gandi.net/en/domain_names/faq/record_types/alias_record.html?highlight=alias) pointing your .com domain to your .info domain but I am unsure if that will achieve what you are waiting. If it doesn’t I’d suggest contacting your provider showing them the documentation above and asking what the equivalent solution is on their platform.